# Hide android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar programmatically

Tags: android, android-activity, android-toolbar

In my activity I do:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

where toolbar is an instance of android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Is there any way after this to hide and show back Toolbar widget programmatically? I already tried

```
toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

but this only makes it invisible and it still takes space, so that content of the activity starts after it, and I see white space instead in the header.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but you probably can easily call `getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Comment: That's really weird, i was under the impression that after you set it as the actionBar it would work as such. Oh well... Learning everyday.

Comment: @Budius Please, ignore me. I was just setting it as a SupportActionBar somewhere later. It was my mistake and your solution works, as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`INVISIBLE` only hides the view.

`GONE` however, will hide the view and prevent it from taking up any space.

```
toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Yep, it's obvious and I'm n00b. Thanks, it works as expected!

Answer (score 6):

If your toolbar is inside the AppBarLayout then you can use **setExpanded** method of AppBarLayout to expand and collapse the toolbar with or without animation.

```
setExpanded(boolean expanded, boolean animate)
```

**this method is available from v23 of Support Library.**

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html#setExpanded(boolean)) for reference.

> As with AppBarLayout scrolling, this method relies on this layout being a direct child of a CoordinatorLayout.
>
> expanded : **true** if the layout should be fully expanded, **false** if it should be fully collapsed
>
> animate : Whether to animate to the new state

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appBar);
```

to expand the toolbar with animation.

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
```

to collapse the toolbar with animation.

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code try this. It worked perfectly for me.

```
    private static final float APPBAR_ELEVATION = 14f;

    private void hideAppBar(final AppBarLayout appBar) {
                appBar.animate().translationY(-appBar.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setDuration(500);

    }
    public void showAppBar(final AppBarLayout appBar){
                appBar.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).setDuration(500).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                appBar.setElevation(APPBAR_ELEVATION);
                            }
                });
    }
```

Hope this might help you